# CnosDB make the default TTL infinitely long

Tags: cnosdb

When I created the database and tested it with the example you provided, a large number of cases were invalid and I had to extend the TTL duration to get the cases to run, and I was hoping that if I created the database with an infinite TTL by default, I would be able to import more historical data to analyze, such as datasets from 1970 or earlier.

Of course, it's okay if Idon't change this little issue because I can set it myself and I can set the TTL duration to 100000 or longer.

This is just a small suggestion, no offense intended.